# Finding limit distributions using Central Limit Theorem/Taylor Series

Tags: self-study, asymptotics

[image]

So, I'm quite stuck on this question and would appreciate help. I am trying to solve this question using the second-order delta method and Taylor expansion (which I believe is the right tool since it allows for improved accuracy of variance estimation).

Here is how I am trying to solve:

*Let sqrt(N)*(0-0o) = parameter

z = parameter/sigma -> d(sqrtN)(0,I3)

When finding first derivatives of our parameter, sqrt(N) = 0 but when sqrt(N) <> 0 this results in a Taylor series.

I am quite lost on this question, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It can help to make an educated guess about the limit distribution.  When $X$ actually has a $N(0,I_3)$ distribution, what is the distribution of $||X||$?